# React-native & typescript: <ImageBackground> component, property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsAttributes &...'

Tags: typescript, react-native

I am struggling to understand why typescript giving me this error message when I use `<ImageBackground>` and `<Image>` component from 'react-native'.

error message:

> No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 2, '(props: ImageBackgroundProps | Readonly): ImageBackground', gave the following error.
> Type '{ children: Element; style: { flex: number; justifyContent: "flex-end"; }; resizeMode: "cover"; source: any; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly'.
> Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly'.
> Overload 2 of 2, '(props: ImageBackgroundProps, context: any): ImageBackground', gave the following error.
> Type '{ children: Element; style: { flex: number; justifyContent: "flex-end"; }; resizeMode: "cover"; source: any; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly'.
> Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly'.

primary source code :

```
import React from "react";
import {
  ImageBackground,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
} from "react-native";

export default function WelcomeScreen() {
  return (
    <ImageBackground
      style={styles.background}
      resizeMode="cover"
      source={require("../assets/images/background.jpg")}
    >
      <View>
        <View style={styles.logginButton}></View>
        <View style={styles.registerButton}></View>
      </View>
    </ImageBackground>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  background: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
  },
  logginButton: {
    width: "100%",
    height: 70,
    backgroundColor: "#fc5c65",
  },
  registerButton: {
    width: "100%",
    height: 70,
    backgroundColor: "#4ecdc4",
  },
});
```

Because the error message sounds like I cannot pass children element in ImageBackground component, so when I changed ImageBackground component to self-closing element (like `<ImageBackground source={image source} />` the error message disappears.

The other solution that I am using currently is to define a custom component referring to expo typescript template. In Themed.tsx, the template defined custom `<Text>` and `<View>` component to apply custom theme.

the code currently works :

```
import React from "react";
import {
  ImageBackground as DefaultImageBackground,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
} from "react-native";

type ImageBackgroundProps = DefaultImageBackground["props"] & {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

function MyBackground(props: ImageBackgroundProps) {
  return <DefaultImageBackground {...props} />;
}

export default function WelcomeScreen() {
  return (
    <MyBackground
      style={styles.background}
      resizeMode="cover"
      source={require("../assets/images/background.jpg")}
    >
      <View>
        <View style={styles.logginButton}></View>
        <View style={styles.registerButton}></View>
      </View>
    </MyBackground>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  background: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
  },
  logginButton: {
    width: "100%",
    height: 70,
    backgroundColor: "#fc5c65",
  },
  registerButton: {
    width: "100%",
    height: 70,
    backgroundColor: "#4ecdc4",
  },
});
```

But I think my solution does not make sense, ImageBackground component should be able to take children element. Is there any syntax error in my primary source code?

Comment: "sounds like I cannot pass children element in ImageBackground component" yes, that is exactly what the error message is telling you. "mageBackground component should be able to take children" yes, it should. What version of react native are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also having this issue. I fixed it by changing the version of node I was using. This issue is present on node `16.14.0` through to `16.15.0`.
I noticed that:

- node `16.14.2` brings in npm `8.5.0`
- node `16.15.0` brings in npm `8.5.5`
- node `16.3.2` brings in npm `8.1.2`
- node `17.0.0` brings in npm `8.1.0`

We just kept the project at `16.13.2` instead of updating.

My current theory is that these differences in npm are causing differences in how tsc interprets rules. I would love to know if I am wrong on that.

Looking in the source code for ImageBackground I see

```
class ImageBackground extends React.Component<$FlowFixMeProps> {
  setNativeProps(props: Object) {
    // Work-around flow
    const viewRef = this._viewRef;
    if (viewRef) {
      viewRef.setNativeProps(props);
    }
  }
```

where <$FlowFixMeProps> is set to:

```
type $FlowFixMeProps = /*unresolved*/ any
```

Is it possible that tsc is not liking any?

Comment: where are using `yarn` :')

Answer (score 2):

What version of react-native are you using, if you are using **0.67.x** please update @types/react-native to **0.67.6**, since that error was fixed.

In case you need to follow @brahim-mahioussi answer you can use [PATCH PACKAGE](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) so you don't loose your changes in the node_modules path, but be sure to add the property as optional:

```
children?: React.ReactNode; //add this line
```

Comment: Thank you!! that fixed it for me as I thought the typings of react-native version was the same as the react-native version (0.67.4), I used 0.67.8 for the typings and that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue with ImageBackgroun.
The problem lies in TypeScript not detecting children props in ImageBackground interface even though it extended it from another interface.
i fix it by adding

```
    children:React.ReactNode;
```

in line **3909** of  **\node_modules@types\react-native\index.d.ts**

```
export interface ImageBackgroundProps extends ImagePropsBase {
imageStyle?: StyleProp<ImageStyle> | undefined;
style?: StyleProp<ViewStyle> | undefined;
imageRef?(image: Image): void;
children:React.ReactNode; //add this line
}
```

now everything work fin, i hop this fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use closed tag. Because inside the ImageBackground type there are no children:

```
<ImageBackground source={require("./src/exemple.png")} resizeMode="cover" />
```

But you'll need to use this style:

```
position: 'absolute',
width: "100%",
height: "100%",
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Expo managed project. Upgrading the following solved the issue.

```
    "@types/react": "^18.0.15",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.69.2",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
```